# String concatenation help needed

Tags: c#, string

I need to make an alpha numeric string given the following conditions.

String length must be 11 characters total.

The first two characters are alpha being either 1 or 2 characters in length.
The last characters numeric and can be 0 to 9 characters.
Any required padding of zeros will come after the alpha characters.

I have the alpha characters = a
I have the numeric characters = b

for example I have tried this:

```
        var a = "J";
        var b = "123456789";

        var c = (a + b).PadLeft(11, '0');

        c = 0J123456789
```

I need the padded zero to be between the 0 and J in this example.

How can I concatenate a + b while ensuring the result is 11 characters in whole?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The first string look like A or B or AB or ZX, then I have another string which can be 1 to 9 digits in length. I need to add the first string to the second string and pad zeros between the first and second strings to ensure 11 characters.

Comment: It sounds like you wish to match `([a-zA-z]{1,2})(\d{1,9})` and then in pseudo-code, `$1+$2+"0"*(11-$1.size-$2.size)`.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks everyone.

Comment: But... What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: I was wrong to think regex would do the concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var a = "a";
var b = "44";
(a + b.PadLeft(11 - a.Length, '0'));
```

Comment: Yes, this works, didn't think about a.length.

Comment: is b.PadLeft before a + ? then pad is between